# Angular Controller method gives older value of scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

> What i am trying to do:

I am creating a directive with input text field. Also taking value and a onChange method as scope parameter. 
A controller is wraped over this directive as u see in the html, this controller provides implementation of onChange method and a model for value.

> Issue i am facing:

see line `console.log($scope.data)`: This statement prints the older value of data object in the console.

Any guess why it is happening.

> JS codde

```
   angular.module('APP', [])
    .directive('txtInput', function () {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            value: '=',
            onChange: '&',
        },
        template: 
          '<div>'+
            '<input type="text" '+
              'ng-change = "onChange()" '+
              'ng-model="value" />'+
          '</div>',
    }
})
.controller('pageCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    userPost: "sdsds",
  }
  $scope.onPostInputChange = function() {
    console.log($scope.data)
  }

})
```

> Here is the HTML

```
<div ng-app='APP' ng-controller="pageCtrl">
    <txt-input 
        value="data.userPost"
        on-change="onPostInputChange()"> </txt-input>
  </div>
```

Also check the copy at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/3035/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ngChange handler gets old value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775267/angular-ngchange-handler-gets-old-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem when using both two-way `=` binding and expression `&` binding in directives and components with isolate scope. Two-way binding
uses a watcher which transfers values from isolate scope to parent scope. The dirty-checking and execution of the watchers happens **after** any invocation of the expression binding. There is a delay between when the expression executes and when the value is transfered to the parent scope.

The solution is to expose the value as a local when the expression binding is invoked. Any expression will then have that value available immediately instead of waiting for a digest cycle.

```
angular.module('APP', [])
    .directive('txtInput', function () {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            value: '=',
            onChange: '&',
        },
        template: 
          '<div>'+
            '<input type="text" '+
              //'ng-change = "onChange()" '+
              //expose value as a local
              'ng-change = "onChange({$value: value}) '+
              'ng-model="value" />'+
          '</div>',
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app='APP' ng-controller="pageCtrl">
    <txt-input 
        value="data.userPost"
        on-change="onPostInputChange($value)">
    </txt-input>
</div>
```

In the parent controller, use the value furnished as an argument to the function:

```
angular.module('APP').controller('pageCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    userPost: "sdsds",
  }
  $scope.onPostInputChange = function(value) {
    //console.log($scope.data)
    console.log(value);
  }
})
```

The [DEMO in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzmd44j0/)

Comment: Thanks georgeawg for detailing.
It makes perfect sense.